# Upload files in Blazor is not going to the uploads folder in wwwroot

Tags: blazor

In my Blazorapplication I have the folder wwwroot/upload where I want to upload images. However the images dont ever make it to the directory.

My code -

```
async Task UploadFile()
{

    if (file != null)
    {
        // Just load into .NET memory to show it can be done
        // Alternatively it could be saved to disk, or parsed in memory, or similar
        var ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
        await file.Data.CopyToAsync(ms);

        status = $"Finished loading {file.Size} bytes from {file.Name}";

        // TODO: Need to upload the file to wwwroot/upload
        var content = new MultipartFormDataContent {
          { new ByteArrayContent(ms.GetBuffer()), "\\upload\\", file.Name }
        };


        await Http.PostAsync("api/Blog/UploadFeaturedImage", content);
    }
}
```

Why is the file not making it to the destination?

UPDATE

My api/Blog/UploadFeaturesImage is below, I believe the issue lies here. Its uploaded all files to a folder on the API project called Upload. How can I tell it to upload to wwwroot/upload please?

```
[Authorize]
    [HttpPost("[action]")]
    public async Task UploadFeaturedImage()
    {
        if (HttpContext.Request.Form.Files.Any())
        {
            foreach (var file in HttpContext.Request.Form.Files)
            {
                var path = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "upload", file.FileName);
                using (var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create))
                {
                    await file.CopyToAsync(stream);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you have error in console log ?

Comment: And how to you process the file on "api/Blog/UploadFeaturedImage" ?

Comment: @aguafrommars Now I have added the api code I can see the issue, its uploading to a folder on the server project, not the Blazor client project. I can see the uploads in a upload folder there. How would I specify the wwwroot folder rather than server folder?

Comment: By customizing its path, but in a Prod environment are you going to have a folder for your blazor app ? I guess no.

Comment: @aguafrommars probably not. What is the best way to achieve this? It makes sense to store the image where it is on the server but how do i then reference it when I need to show the image in the Blazor app?

Comment: In your blazor app you gonna get access to your files using `<a>` link I guess, thoses links should point to your files on your server. So it's fine to store static file in a server folder.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if this will help you, but I have a Nuget package called BlazorFileUpload that comes with a sample project:

https://github.com/DataJuggler/BlazorFileUpload

This is based upon BlazorInputFile by SteveSanderson, the creator of Blazor at Microsoft.

Razor Code:

@using DataJuggler.Blazor.FileUpload

```
<FileUpload CustomSuccessMessage="Your file uploaded successfully." 
    OnChange="OnFileUploaded" FilterByExtension="true" 
    ShowStatus="false"  PartialGuidLength="10" MaxFileSize="4194304"        
    ShowCustomButton="true" ButtonText="Select File" 
    CustomButtonClassName="buttonwide"        
    AllowedExtensions=".jpg;.png;" ShowResetButton="true" OnReset="OnReset" 
    ResetButtonClassName="button" ResetButtonText="Reset"
    CustomExtensionMessage="Only .jpg and .png files are allowed." 
    AppendPartialGuid="true"                
    FileTooLargeMessage="The file uploaded must be 4 megabytes or smaller.">
</FileUpload>
```

The OnFileUploaded eventcallback is called after the file is uploaded:

```
/// <summary>
/// method returns the File Uploaded
/// </summary>
private void OnFileUploaded(UploadedFileInfo uploadedFileInfo)
{
    // if aborted
    if (uploadedFileInfo.Aborted)
    {
        // get the status
        status = uploadedFileInfo.ErrorMessage;
    }
    else
    {
        // get the status
        status = "The file " + uploadedFileInfo.FullName + " was uploaded.";

        // other information about the file is available
        //DateTime lastModified = uploadedFileInfo.LastModified;
        //string nameAsItIsOnDisk = uploadedFileInfo.NameWithPartialGuid;
        //string partialGuid = uploadedFileInfo.PartialGuid;
        //long size = uploadedFileInfo.Size;
        //string type = uploadedFileInfo.Type;

        // The above information can be used to display, and / or process a file
    }
}
```

The sample project is located in the Samples folder of the Git Repo listed above.

The FileUpload component default UploadDirectory is 'wwwroot/Upload', so it should work for you:

```
[Parameter]
public string UploadFolder { get; set; } = "wwwroot/Upload/";
```

I am almost done with a BlazorImageGallery sample, it should be done later this week:

[image]

There is also a video that comes with the BlazorFileUpload project if anyone wants to watch: https://youtu.be/Hj_k90mifSQ

Maybe it will help someone.